# UDP protocol not supported in mono?

Tags: c#, sockets, mono, udp

I do not understand because it gives me error code:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(
    AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
    SocketType.Stream, 
    ProtocolType.Udp
);
```

Return an error:

```
me@machine:~/Demo/bin/Debug$ mono Demo.exe
Marshaling clicked signal
Exception in Gtk# callback delegate
  Note: Applications can use GLib.ExceptionManager.UnhandledException to handle the exception.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Protocol not supported
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor (AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  ...
   at Gtk.Application.gtk_main()
   at Gtk.Application.Run()
   at Demo.MainClass.Main(System.String[] args)
```

But my system support UDP connections:

```
me@machine:~$ nc -u -v host.com 53
Connection to host.com 53 port [udp/domain] succeeded!
```

That I have done wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a `SocketType.Stream` for UDP doesn't work, as UDP is not a stream protocol (TCP is). You almost certainly want to use `SocketType.Dgram` (datagram) for UDP. UDP stands for "User Datagram Protocol" as it is functionally built on datagrams.